# Enable package-wide extensions in "stack runghc"

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

If I have the following in my `package.yaml` file:

```
default-extensions:
- LambdaCase
```

I am able to compile my project which makes use of the [LambdaCase syntax](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/guide-to-ghc-extensions/basic-syntax-extensions#lambdacase) like this:

```
myFunction = \case
  Nothing -> "empty"
  Just x -> x
```

However, if the project is run with `stack runghc`, the `LambdaCase` extension is not respected.

My project has about 200 modules, so I would rather not have to add `{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}` to the top of every file.

Is there a way to enable a project-wide GHC extension with `stack runghc` analogously to the package-wide `default-extensions` property in `package.yaml`?

Comment: One answer is to use something like `stack runghc -- -XLambdaCase filename.hs`. I _think_ it's possible to achieve this via a `.ghci` file as well, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, stack should probably have some better support for this -
 see https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3338 .

I'd say the summary is that `stack runghc` came before `stack ghci`, it's ended up having a much simpler meaning that does not take cabal files into account at all.  Not sure how to make things consistent and intuitive on the commandline without changing the meaning of `runghc`.

In that issue, I describe a hacky workaround.  Copying it here:

Here's a workaround for now.  Put the following in `~/.local/bin/stack-run-ghc.sh` and make it user executable:

```
#/bin/sh
ghc $(echo "$*" | sed 's/--interactive//g')
```

This takes the arguments, removes `--interactive`, and calls ghc.  With this, I can build stack using ghc via the following:

`stack ghci --with-ghc stack-run-ghc.sh --ghci-options src/main/Main.hs`